# Insert String in ArrayList from Bundle

Tags: android, arrays, bundle

I try to add String from Bundle to my ArrayList but when I add from bundle Value the ArrayList dont show image.

```
List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    imgUrls.add(locationIv1);
    imgUrls.add(locationIv2);
```

Bundle:

```
locationIv1 = (mBundle.getString("Image1"));
locationIv2 = (mBundle.getString("Image2"));
```

If I try to put value like that, it's work fine

```
List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    imgUrls.add("url.exemple.jpg");
```

Comment: Make sure you declare locationIv1 and locationIv2 before you add it to imgUrls.

Comment: They are declared I have test for Im sure

Comment: Are you sure to pass the Bundle correctly? Please add this to your code and check weather your url is shown: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), locationIv1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: the value is not declared but when i try in TextView I saw my Url

Comment: Does this mean locationIv1 is definitely your url and not empty?

Comment: if i try locationNom.setText((mBundle.getString("Image1"))); TextView show my Url but if i try to add in List my value is not declared, I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the Strings **before** adding them.

```
//first declare
locationIv1 = (mBundle.getString("Image1"));
locationIv2 = (mBundle.getString("Image2"));

//then add
List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    imgUrls.add(locationIv1);
    imgUrls.add(locationIv2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put "image1" in my TextView LocationName I saw the Url but no value is the Toast.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_list);


    locationNom = findViewById(R.id.tvDnom);
    locationAdresse = findViewById(R.id.tvdAdresse);
    List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    imgUrls.add(locationIv1);
    imgUrls.add(locationIv2);


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), locationIv1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_detail);
    ViewPagerAdapterDetail adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterDetail(this, imgUrls);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null){

       locationNom.setText((mBundle.getString("Nom")));
       locationAdresse.setText(mBundle.getString("Adresse"));
       locationIv1 = (mBundle.getString("Image1"));
       locationIv2 = (mBundle.getString("Image2"));
    }
}
```